# Facebook event picture size

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get a different size for an event picture. This does not appear to work.

I tried:

https://graph.facebook.com/160348937502069/picture?type=square

https://graph.facebook.com/160348937502069/picture?width=40&height=60

But this all seems to return the same (bigger) image.

Yet when I look at this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/ it specifically says that event pictures are supported.

Am I doing something wrong or is that page out of date?

On another note, is it not possible to get the picture size back from facebook? That would solve a lot of issues...

Answer (score 0):

Is the Event using a Cover Image or the old profile image?
You above code is definitly working if the event uses a cover image. I think Event Profile images are not supported.

Greets

Comment: I'm just using the event ID in my examples above to get the picture - I do not know the internals of what kind of image the event is using